# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7559).

Answer (score 28):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Answer (score 18):

[image: TeX online documentation lookup system]

Answer (score 15):

[image: The TeX User Group]

Answer (score 15):

[image: TEXample.net]

Answer (score 15):

[image: PGFPlots Plot example gallery]

Answer (score 14):

[image: LaTeX]

Comment: When it appears on the main site, the aspect ratio is not kept...

Comment: That's good to know. I should properbly cut out the title and just have the bird then? @CarLaTeX

Comment: I'm not an expert, but see the requirements: _The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels_...

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX I had overlooked that. I will try to do something in the near future.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 13):

[image: TeX Live - cross-platform TeX software]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Gruppo Utilizzatori Italiani di TeX]

Comment: Copied from the last year.

Comment: That P.S. is pure gold

Comment: @AndreaL. LOL ;)

Answer (score 11):

[image: The LaTeX Font Catalogue]

Comment: I put a new image at https://www.dropbox.com/s/xh259kxt9m7zivs/FontCatalogue.png?dl=0 (can’t figure out how to edit this answer so as to replace the first version while keeping the required format). It’s the same design but turned into `.png` by `mutool` rather than the GIMP, since the latter makes it look as if the kerning between ‘o’ and ‘g’ in the web address is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for replacing the image, @DaiBowen

Answer (score 8):

[image: TeXwelt - Fragen und Antworten zu TeX auf Deutsch]

Answer (score 8):

[image: LaTeX Community Forum - Talk about TeX and LaTeX]

Answer (score 8):

[image: TeX talk - news and interviews]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 7):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from last year.

Answer (score 6):

[image: TeX questions and answers in French]

Answer (score 6):

[image: visit glossaries gallery]

Comment: Copied from last year

Answer (score 6):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Answer (score 5):

[image: LaTeX template for russian PhD thesis (LaTeX-шаблон для кандидатской диссертации и её автореферата)]